# boost pool_allocator memory pool behavior clarification

Tags: c++, boost, boost-pool

The boost documentation as below:

> **Note**
>
> The underlying `singleton_pool` used by the this allocator constructs a pool instance that is never freed. This means that memory allocated by the allocator can be still used after `main()` has completed, but may mean that some memory checking programs will complain about leaks.

I am confused since I checked the code and the `singleton_pool` still seem to be created only on the heap of the current process. I.e. if the process is killed by the OS, such pool will be released anyway? Then the above notes merely means if some daemon thread keeps on and such pool is still available after main()? Or it actually means the pool won't be released even after the entire process is killed?

It also seems to me both `pool_allocator` and `fast_pool_allocator` are using the identical mechanism to allocate memory i.e. from such a `singleton_pool` singleton. However this note isn't specified for the `fast_pool_allocator`. I would reckon both of them behaves the same for such a note above. Am I correct?

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: "after main has completed" but before the program has exited... There are still a few things to do after main. But of course the memory is returned to the OS when the program dies (assuming your OS handles it, not some limited embedded platform).

Comment: @MarcGlisse That's it?? I thought there is some black magic I didn't grasp on code ... D'or.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Mind if write that as the answer so I could accept thanks :)

Comment: @MarcGlisse As Alex suggests that should be an answer not a comment. It would be worth noting that thing that happen after `main()` that the note might be relevant to include anything registered to `std::atexit()` and the destructor of file scope variables (i.e. global variables).

Comment: @AlexSuo Sure, you go ahead and write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`singleton_pool` implements thread-safe(under some conditions) singleton without locks, using the feature of initialization of non-local static variables. The part of source code:

```
template <typename Tag,
    unsigned RequestedSize,
    typename UserAllocator,
    typename Mutex,
    unsigned NextSize,
    unsigned MaxSize >
class singleton_pool
{
   ...
   struct object_creator
   {
      object_creator()
      {  // This constructor does nothing more than ensure that instance()
         //  is called before main() begins, thus creating the static
         //  T object before multithreading race issues can come up.
         singleton_pool<Tag, RequestedSize, UserAllocator, Mutex, NextSize, MaxSize>::get_pool();
      }
      inline void do_nothing() const
      {
      }
   };
   static object_creator create_object;
}; // struct singleton_pool
```

non-local variables are initialized as part of program startup, before the execution of the main function begins and get torn down when the program terminates. So that `singleton_pool` will be created before the `main()`, and destroyed after `main()`. If the process is terminated anyway, of course pool will be released.